# SSH into the EC2 instance on Windows is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to SSH into my AWS EC2 instance. I am not using putty. I am using Virtual Environment and python SDK instead. So before I SSH into the server, I need to activate the virtual environment. But it is not working as I expected.  This is what I have done so far.

I activated the virtual environment running the following command.

```
~\eb-ve\Scripts\activate
```

It was activated. Then I downloaded the SSH Key in pem format which is attached to my EC2 server. After I have download, the file I changed the permission of the file as follow.

```
chmod 0400 ForkProd.pem
```

Then I tried to SSH into the server running the following command.

```
ssh -i "ForkProd.pem" root@ec2-13-229-232-13.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Then I got the following error.

```
Permissions for 'ForkProd.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "ForkProd.pem": bad permissions
root@ec2-13-229-232-13.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I remember I did the same to the other project before and it worked. I am not sure what went wrong this time. What is wrong with the configuration and how can I fix it?

Comment: Two different PEM files?

Comment: You've modified the permissions of `ForkTest.pem`, but you're using a different file, `ForkProd.pem`, in your `ssh` command. What are the permissions of the file you're actually using?

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the question. I have been using the same file actually. I use the same file too. It just does not work.

Comment: Related: [Windows SSH: Permissions for 'private-key' are too open](https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open)

Answer (score 0):

I've definitely had this issue in the past on Windows machines. If I remember correctly and your permissions on the key all check out, then it might be something to do with the .pem key being in your home directory or the root.

If you move the .pem into a less 'global' folder e.g. *C:\Users\your-username\Documents\ForkProd.pem* you may have better luck.

edit: +1 for the link from jarmod in the comments above

Comment: I tried it moving the SSH key into Documents folder. But it does not work either.